# Two instances of my android application are running....How to avoid this?

Tags: android

Here is my problem -

1. I copied my .apk file onto phone memory card and launch my application clicking on it and it allows me to install my application.I install my application.Finally,I got system installation pop up containing two options "Open" and "Done".When i click "Open" my application got launched.Up to this point everything is working without any problem.
2. Now in my application I click on a button and some download is taking place as a result(Showing progress dialog).Now I press a Home button,so my application goes to background.
3. Now I again launch my application by going inside Menu and clicking on my application icon.
4. Expected result - Still I Should see Progress Dialog for downloading.
   Actual result - A new instance/session of my application is getting started.

So how to avoid this so that only one and one instance/session of my application should run.

Answer (score 10):

@Palejandro, here you are. Put the code below into your **main activity** `onCreate()` method:

```
// Possible work around for market launches. See
// http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2373
// for more details. Essentially, the market launches the main activity
// on top of other activities.
// We never want this to happen. Instead, we check if we are the root
// and if not, we finish.
if (!isTaskRoot()) {
    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String intentAction = intent.getAction();
    if (intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) && intentAction != null && intentAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Main Activity is not the root. Finishing Main Activity instead of launching.");
        finish();
        return;
    }
}
```

I used this piece of code in my projects and it works fine!

Comment: can you plz explain what is isTaskRoot flag? How what and when to set it?

Comment: It means that current activity is a root activity of the current task. In other words it was launched with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag: http://goo.gl/QFkjp

Comment: This saved my life.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I needed. This OS keeps surprising me...

Answer (score 8):

I believe you need to put

```
<activity
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
</activity>
```

in the manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

what do your `OnPause`, `OnResume` and `OnCreate`?
I will bet money you are not saving anything OnPause, and starting a new instance all the time via OnCreate.

You should read the notes on [Activity Lifecycles.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle)

Comment: I can't recommend reading and re-reading that link for new Android developers. You need to study it.

Comment: The above described scenario of two application instances will not occur if i directly run my application in Eclipse with USB connected to device.In this case my application automatically get launched.I don't need to copy .apk file to memory card and manually install it.

Comment: do you see two separate activities when you go into the Task Manager?
you might be seeing two different activities because you are installing both a debug apk AND the release apk.  You can then have 2 variations of the same activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't got this sorted yet, I would say your app is actually being killed when home is pressed, or perhaps you have a bug that doesn't latch onto whatever object is keeping state.

Comment: Sorry this isn't the case for this guy's problem. Its usually due to the install wizard.

Answer (score 0):

// put below code in your launcher activity before call super and setcontentview()

ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

```
    // get the info from the currently running task
    List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(10);
    boolean alreadyTask=false;
    for(ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo info : taskInfo){
        ComponentName componentInfo = info.topActivity;
        String value= componentInfo.getPackageName();
        if(value.contains(getPackageName()) && !info.topActivity.getClassName().contains(getPackageName()+".LauncherActivity")){
            alreadyTask=true;
            Log.i(TAG, "second instance found!!!");
            break;
        }
    }

    if(alreadyTask){
        finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution but the problem is that the intent used to start the app is different when you open it directly from install compared to opening it from your home screen. Since it will get started by two different intents it will open a new instance the second time round.

A quick work around is to avoid pressing "Open" when you have installed the application. Press "Done" and then find the application yourself.

See: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2373