# Lifecycle of AsyncTask and Application?

Tags: java, android

My application starts with creating `MyApplication extends Application`

I have service that runs on background by alarm and when service done running (obtaining GPS position) I start `AsyncTask` from that service to do sync with my server.

Here is my understanding:

1. Only one `Application` can run at a time in Android OS. I'm talking about instance of MY application. So, there is no way I can have 2 instances of my Application object from the same package running.
2. If I see messages I log inside `Application.onCreate()` that means that OS shut down my Application.
3. Service runs on UI thread even though not visible.
4. If I spawn `AsyncTask` from my service and OS kills my application - AsyncTask get's terminated as well. There is no way I can control graceful termination of my AsyncTask.
5. If I had Alarm scheduled and Application was down - OS will send broadcast which will in turn start Application and then service.
6. Alarm starts service every 5 minutes. Service tries to obtain location for UP TO 1 minute and starts AsyncTask when done. So, my AsyncTask have 4 minutes before next service start. Inside Async task I do DB access and this causing issues like listed below..

Is my understanding correct? Reason I'm asking this because I write logs from all the devices that run application and sometimes observe weird behaviors. Most devices run Application almost 24/7 but on some I see Application_Start logged event all the time.

Is there any way to simulate Application shutdown by system for my testing? Is what I'm doing wrong and need to be done differently? I'd like to syncronize my background processing because there is a lot of data read/write and it is blocking..

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
 at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file (code 14)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForCursorWindow(Native Method)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java:838)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:836)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:143)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
 at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:196)
 at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:236)
 at com.idatt.data.LockData.Lock(LockData.java:37)
 at com.idatt.common.AsyncProcessor.doInBackground(AsyncProcessor.java:154)
 at com.idatt.common.AsyncProcessor.doInBackground(AsyncProcessor.java:18)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
 ... 4 more
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file (code 14)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForCursorWindow(Native Method)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java:838)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:836)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:143)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
 at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:196)
 at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:236)
 at com.idatt.data.LockData.Lock(LockData.java:37)
 at com.idatt.common.AsyncProcessor.doInBackground(AsyncProcessor.java:154)
 at com.idatt.common.AsyncProcessor.doInBackground(AsyncProcessor.java:18)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. wrong . android really can run multiple processes and threads (and apps) at the same time . it does it all the time , though it usually gives the foreground app more CPU than the rest . also , even though i've never done it , it's possible to run multiple instances of your own app and use multiple processes.

   however , if your app shouldn't use CPU while not in the foreground (like a game, for example) , please try to do so . nobody wants to have an app that drains the battery while it's not even seem to be running.
2. very wrong . onCreate of the app occurs at the beginning . if it occurs multiple times,  it means that it was restarted (either by the OS or by the user).
3. correct . for background work , use a worker thread.
4. depends . if you have the service started as a foreground service (with a notification) , the OS will give the killing of the service a very low priority .
5. depends on what your app does . if it does it , it will occur this way .
6. when you create a background service , you have to remember that the OS is allowed to close it whenever it thinks it doesn't do an important task . that's why you have to be able to resume your work when such a thing occurs .

Comment: By #1 I mean my application, not all applications. I'm saying that if inside Application.onCreate i log events and see them - that means OS was stopping my application

Comment: #1 really bother me. Not about ALL applications installed. I'm talking only about MY application. How can I run multiple instances of my application if I want to?

Comment: Searches on google show that it is not possible to run multiple instances of the same application from same APK: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918973/two-instances-of-my-android-application-are-running-how-to-avoid-this

Because if its possible - it's a big problem in my case

Comment: you can set any process to any of your services . for each activity you can create a new instance and you can also create multiple tasks .

Comment: I know that. But I expect MyApplication extends Application to be only ONE so I can syncronize stuff inside this object

Comment: well i'm not sure what you're trying to achieve . please explain so that i could give you a solution . you can count on that the class that extends Application will only have one instance through the app lifecycle , and that it runs in the UI thread . you can also have singletons managed there for whatever you wish .

Comment: See this question - it will give better idea on what I'm doing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675445/syncronizing-tasks-in-android

Comment: Also, I would accept your answer but this is wrong: "it's possible to run multiple instances of your own app". You said in #2 exactly what I think happens. My app get's destroyed.

Comment: ok . for multiple instances of the Application , all you need to do is to set the process for the things that you wish to have more of them. for example , if you set a process for activity1 and a different one for activity2 , when activity1 will open activity2 , the onCreate of the Application class will occur twice (meaning 2 instances of it are now present) . you can check it out using getApplicationContext too. in short , there's one Application instance per process of your app .

Comment: about #2 , that's the normal behavior . if only one process is used (which is the usual case) , onCreate should occur only once . what you've written says that the app is destroyed , which is incorrect - it was just created.

Comment: about what you're trying to achieve , here's a suggestion: have all the internet communication run via the service , and if you need the communication to continue even if the user has left the app for a moment , set the service to be a foreground service .

Comment: Ok, if I do not set process in my manifest and never do anything like this in code than I should have only 1 instance of Application, correct? The only thing I do which is not really "standard" is I call `i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` to start Activity from alarm receiver. But that still should start it in a same process, correct?

Comment: well , if the app wasn't destroyed by the OS before , then yes , it will stay the exact same process and there will only be a single instance of the Application class which won't change as long as the process is alive.